# Summing over an array and then multiply by a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
Fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'kiwi']

A = [4,  3,  10,  8]

B = {'apple': {'Bill': 4, 'Jan': 3, 'Frank': 5},
     'orange': {'Bill': 0, 'Jan': 1, 'Frank': 5},
     'banana': {'Bill': 8, 'Jan': 6, 'Frank': 2},
     'kiwi': {'Bill': 4, 'Jan': 2, 'Frank': 7}}
```

I am trying to sum over all the fruits of A and multiply that by B. I am having trouble doing this A is an array of just numbers and B is a dictionary. This is where I am getting confused. I am a new Python user. The numbers in A are in the same position relative to Fruits (the first number in A is the number of apples). Would this involve using sum(A)?

Sorry folks for the lack of details. Here is some clarity. I have fruits and I have numbers of fruits that each person has based on the type. I am wanting to sum all of the values of each fruit type in B such that I get:

```
 apple = 12
 orange = 6
 banana = 16
 kiwi = 13
```

Now, I want to multiple these numbers, by A, but keeping in mind that the first number in A, is apple, then orange, and so on to get a new array:

```
 Solution = [48,18,160,104] #solution order is apple, orange, banana, kiwi
```

Comment: The question is not clear. What would be the expected result with this data?

Comment: show the math as you would work it out by hand and we'll be able to help

Comment: Thank you. I am working on that now to update my question.

Comment: I think the code needs to show things like "the first number in A is the number of apples," in the variable names, and in the way the data is structured, rather than you just telling us that

Comment: You don't really need the list "fruits," since the keys of B are the same as the list of fruits. For instance, "for fruit in B:" iterates over the same fruit-name strings as "for fruit in fruits:"

Comment: At the very least, "fruits" and "A" should be a dictionary instead of two lists, since one indicates the index of the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want to multply the sum of the fruits for each person (in `B`) by the cost in `A`, you can do the following list comprehension:

```
>>> [cost * sum(B[fruit].values()) for cost, fruit in zip(A, Fruits)]
[48, 18, 160, 104]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fruit_costs = {fruit_name:fruit_cost for fruit_name,fruit_cost in zip(Fruits,A)
for fruit in Fruits:
    print "Fruit:",fruit,"=",sum(B[fruit].values())*fruit_costs[fruit]
```

I guess?

Comment: I don't see any other way to do it, unless they want the sum by name (i.e. `Bill`, `Jan`, and `Frank` here.)

Answer (score 0):

Merge everything into one big dictionary; everything here is just properties of fruits:

```
>>> for i, fruit in enumerate(fruits):
>>>     B[fruit]['cost'] = A[i]
>>> B
{'banana': {'Frank': 2, 'Jan': 6, 'Bill': 8, 'cost': 10}, 'apple': {'Frank': 5, 'Jan': 3, 'Bill': 4, 'cost': 4}, 'orange': {'Frank': 5, 'Jan': 1, 'Bill': 0, 'cost': 3}, 'kiwi': {'Frank': 7, 'Jan': 2, 'Bill': 4, 'cost': 8}}
```

Rename "B" to "fruits" (losing the old value of "fruits"):

```
>>> fruits = B
```

Calculate fruit cost for each fruit:

```
>>> for fruitname in fruits:
...     fruit = test.B[fruitname]
...     fruit['total'] = fruit['Frank'] + fruit['Bill'] + fruit['Jan']
...     fruit['total cost'] = fruit['cost'] * fruit['total']
... 
>>> fruits
{'banana': {'total': 16, 'Frank': 2, 'Jan': 6, 'total cost': 160, 'Bill': 8, 'cost': 10}, 'apple': {'total': 12, 'Frank': 5, 'Jan': 3, 'total cost': 48, 'Bill': 4, 'cost': 4}, 'orange': {'total': 6, 'Frank': 5, 'Jan': 1, 'total cost': 18, 'Bill': 0, 'cost': 3}, 'kiwi': {'total': 13, 'Frank': 7, 'Jan': 2, 'total cost': 104, 'Bill': 4, 'cost': 8}}
```

Calculate total cost:

```
>>> total = sum(fruits[fruit]['total cost'] for fruit in fruits)
```

Or if that last line is awkward since you're new to Python, you can expand it out into:

```
>>> total = 0
>>> for fruitname in fruits:
...     fruit = fruits[fruitname]
...     total += fruit['total cost']
...
```

Either way:

```
>>> total
330
```